# Whoops, looks like something went wrong. Laravel

Tags: laravel

Whoops, looks like something went wrong. Laravel 5.0  when i type http://localhost:8000/admin/categories. It show Categories Admin Panel, Here you can view, delete, and create new categories.

this is my index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
    <div id="admin">
        <h1>Categories Admin Panel</h1><hr>
        <p>Here you can view, delete, and create new categories.</p>
        <h2>Categories</h2><hr>
        <ul>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <li>
                    {!! $category->name !!} - 
                    {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/categories/destroy', 'class'=>'form-inline')) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('id', $category->id) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('delete') !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        <h2>Create New Category</h2><hr>
        @if($errors->has())
            <div id="form-errors">
            <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end form-errors -->
        @endif
        {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/categories/create')) !!}
        <p>
            {!! Form::label('name') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name') !!}
        </p>
        {!! Form::submit('Create Category', array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div><!-- end admin -->
@stop
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong. Laravel 5.0  when i type http://localhost:8000/admin/categories Categories Admin Panel

Comment: There can be many problems in this code snippet. $categories can be null, $errors->has() may cause problem. You should provide more details. Check laravel.log or laravel-date.log in storage/logs directory and provide more details.

Comment: set debug to true in .env or in the app.php file

Comment: Check your error log.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your error showing code with if statement.
It should look like this:

```
<ul>
    @if($errors->any())    
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
        @endforeach
    @endif    
</ul>
```